# How to test a method that requires a model as a argument (Java, Springboot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm new to testing methods with JUnit. I'm currently working on a Springboot application, which I want to test properly now. However, I don't understand what needs to be done in order to test a method that has a model as an argument.

The method I want to test:

```
public void updateCheckoutIncome(Model model, MonetaryAmount amount) {
        checkoutIncome = checkoutIncome.add(amount);
        model.addAttribute("checkoutIncome", checkoutIncome);
    }
```

I then went ahead and wrote this test file that should test the class above:

```
public class AccountingManagementTest {

    @SpringBootTest
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    public class AccountingControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        MockMvc mvc;
        @Autowired
        AccountingManagement accountingManagement;


        
        @Test
        @WithMockUser(roles = "BOSS,EMPLOYEE")
        void updateCheckoutIncomeTest() throws Exception {

            MonetaryAmount checkoutIncome = Money.of(10.00, EURO);
            Model cart = new ModelAttribute("cart");

            accountingManagement.updateCheckoutIncome(cart, Money.of(19.99, EURO));
            Assertions.assertEquals(Money.of(29.99, EURO), checkoutIncome);

        }
    }
}
```

**My question is:** How do I test create the "model", that I need to pass along to the method call in the test? I could find a method creating a new "ModelAndView" element, but my method requires a "Model" element. Can anyone guide me what I'm missing?

*To explain the model a little bit: This defines a view element in springboot. If you're having a model "cart" for example, this contains information which will be passed over to an HTML file (for example).*

Comment: You might want to take a look at the implementing classes of such `Model` interface (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html) and create an instance of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case you should use `ArgumentCaptor` which will capture the argument(model) you passed to your method (updateCheckoutIncome), then you can verify the values of attributes of your model.

for more details check out this tutorial:

https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Weirdly enough, that seems to work - almost: I can "satisfy" the arguments with it, however the test-result is not true. I added this right below the ? `AccountingManagement` tag: 
`@Mock
Model model;`

But it should give a 29.99 as a result, instead of it returning 10.00. Do you have any idea why?